# How to pass variable to a function created through the guide

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have developed a GUI in MATLAB GUIDE. What is the best way to make data from an external function or class available to functions created by GUIDE?

Answer (score 3):

The links supplied by [ymihere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704391/how-to-pass-variable-to-a-function-created-through-the-guide/705267#705267) look very helpful. In addition, some of the options (nested functions and using [GUIDATA](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/guidata.html)) discussed at those links are addressed in another post on SO: [How to create a GUI inside a function in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272511/how-to-create-a-gui-inside-a-function-in-matlab) There are a couple of examples there of how the code looks for each case.

I am personally partial to using nested functions, as I feel like it creates shorter, cleaner code in most cases. However, it's probably the more difficult of the methods for sharing application data if you are a newer MATLAB user (it can take a little getting used to). The easiest option for you may be to set the 'UserData' property on your call to your function (as suggested by [ymihere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704391/how-to-pass-variable-to-a-function-created-through-the-guide/705267#705267)). If you saved your GUIDE GUI to "myGUI.m", then you would call:

```
>> hGUI = myGUI('UserData','hello');
```

where **hGUI** is a handle to your GUI object. You can then get the 'UserData' property to see that it contains the string 'hello':

```
>> get(hGUI,'UserData')

ans =

hello
```

Instead of 'hello', you can put anything you want, like a structure of data. You should be able to access the 'UserData' field of the figure from within the callbacks of your GUIDE m-file. You will have to get the figure handle from the **handles** argument passed to your callbacks.

**EDIT:** One drawback to using the 'UserData' property, or some of the other methods which attach data to an object, is that the data could be accidentally (or intentionally) overwritten or otherwise corrupted by the user or other applications. The benefit of using nested functions to share data between your GUI callbacks is that it insulates your code from anything the user or another application might do. Conversely, using [global variables](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/global.html) can be rather dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what you want to do exactly, but you may probably want to use the figure's UserData property:

Passing somevar when opening the form myfig:

```
h = myfig('UserData', somevar);
```

or later:

```
h = myfig();
[...]
set(h, 'UserData', somevar);
```

In the figure you can access the property with:

```
function some_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    somevar = get(hObject, 'UserData');
```

See [link text](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/index.html?/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/creating_guis/f13-998449.html) and [link text](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/index.html?/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/creating_guis/f5-998352.html)