# Problems with displaying edited pictures in a GUI created in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I have an assignment to create a GUI using MATLAB GUIDE and am having a problem with displaying an edited picture. I need to have buttons that edit the picture (eg. remove red, blue, green components and rotate) and display that edited picture. I am using `imshow` to display the edited picture but it displays in a new window and shuts down the GUI I had running. Can anyone help?

I've been working on this and have tried numerous different ways of fixing the problem but none worked. However, I am using MATLAB 7.0.1, and 7.7.0 might have an update for this problem.

Comment: The links I gave below pertain to the newest version of MATLAB (2009a). I'm not sure how much has changed since v7.0.1, pertaining to this specific problem. I know IMSHOW was acting slightly different when I ran it in v7.1 versus v7.7. If you could post parts (not all) of your code, perhaps we could help more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you first plot the image with [`imshow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html), have it return a handle to the image object it creates:

```
A = (the initial matrix of image data);
hImage = imshow(A);
```

Then, to update the image with new data, try the following instead of calling `imshow` again:

```
B = (modification of the original image matrix A);
set(hImage, 'CData', B);
```

Using the [`set`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) command will change the image object you already created (a list of image object properties can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image-properties.html)).

Alternatively, you can also add additional parameters to a call to `imshow` to tell it which axes object to plot the image in:

```
hAxes = (the handle to an axes object);
imshow(A, 'Parent', hAxes);
```

---

**EDIT:**

Addressing your additional problem of sharing GUI data between functions, you should check out the MATLAB documentation [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html). As noted there, there are a few different ways to pass data between different functions involved in a GUI: nesting functions (mentioned on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/272511/52738)), using the 'UserData' property of objects (mentioned on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/704391/52738)), or using the functions [`setappdata`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html)/[`getappdata`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html) or [`guidata`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html). The `guidata` option may be best for use with GUIs made in GUIDE.

Comment: The problem I have now is that is doesn't recognize that there is a variable 'hImage.' I think that is because I am trying to edit the picture in a different function in the GUI. How can I carry over the hImage data?

Answer (score 0):

The GUI m file functions automatically assign the image data to a variable called `hObject`. Once you have done your image alteration, you have to reassign the new data to `hObject`:

```
hObject = imshow(newimagedata)
```

Don't forget to update and save this operation by:

```
guidata(hObject, handles)
```