# What is a function handle and how is it useful?

Tags: matlab, function, function-handle

Can somebody explain to me the meaning of the `@` (function handle) operator and why to use it?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The [function handle operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html) in MATLAB acts essentially like a pointer to a specific instance of a function. Some of the other answers have discussed a few of its uses, but I'll add another use here that I often have for it: maintaining access to functions that are no longer "in scope".

For example, the following function initializes a value `count`, and then returns a function handle to a nested function `increment`:

```
function fHandle = start_counting(count)

  disp(count);
  fHandle = @increment;

  function increment
    count = count+1;
    disp(count);
  end

end
```

Since the function `increment` is a [nested function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html), it can only be used within the function `start_counting` (i.e. the workspace of `start_counting` is its "scope"). However, by returning a handle to the function `increment`, I can still use it outside of `start_counting`, and it still retains access to the variables in the workspace of `start_counting`! That allows me to do this:

```
>> fh = start_counting(3);  % Initialize count to 3 and return handle
     3

>> fh();  % Invoke increment function using its handle
     4

>> fh();
     5
```

Notice how we can keep incrementing count even though we are outside of the function `start_counting`. But you can do something even more interesting by calling `start_counting` again with a different number and storing the function handle in another variable:

```
>> fh2 = start_counting(-4);
    -4

>> fh2();
    -3

>> fh2();
    -2

>> fh();  % Invoke the first handle to increment
     6

>> fh2();  % Invoke the second handle to increment
    -1
```

Notice that these two different counters operate independently. The function handles `fh` and `fh2` point to different instances of the function `increment` with different workspaces containing unique values for `count`.

In addition to the above, using function handles in conjunction with nested functions can also help streamline GUI design, as I illustrate in [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/425347/52738).

Comment: One thing that's important to note is that functions created with the function keyword and functions created by the @ operator have different scoping rules. hGetCount=@getCount;function c=getCount; c=count; end; does the lookup of the count variable at evaluation time (using lexical scoping), as you describe above.  The function hGetCount=@()count; will have the count variable's value substituted at creation time.

Comment: Function handles allow you to work with nested functions or subfunctions, from outside of the main function. They can aid you in GUI programming.

Comment: @ Mr. Fooz: Good point! Anonymous functions created with the @ operator will simply substitute values for the variables that exist in the workspace at the time they are created, while "normal" functions have their own workspaces for storing variables.

Answer (score 18):

Function handles are an extremely powerful tool in matlab. A good start is to read the online help, which will give you far more than I can. At the command prompt, type

```
doc function_handle
```

A function handle is a simple way to create a function in one line. For example, suppose I wished to numerically integrate the function sin(k*x), where k has some fixed, external value. I could use an inline function, but a function handle is much neater. Define a function

```
k = 2;
fofx = @(x) sin(x*k);
```

See that I can now evaluate the function fofx at the command line. MATLAB knows what k is, so we can use fofx as a function now.

```
fofx(0.3)
ans =
         0.564642473395035
```

In fact, we can pass fofx around, effectively as a variable. For example, lets call quad to do the numerical integration. I'll pick the interval [0,pi/2].

```
quad(fofx,0,pi/2)
ans =
         0.999999998199215
```

As you can see, quad did the numerical integration. (By the way, an inline function would have been at least an order of magitude slower, and far less easy to work with.)

```
x = linspace(0,pi,1000);
tic,y = fofx(x);toc
Elapsed time is 0.000493 seconds.
```

By way of comparison, try an inline function.

```
finline = inline('sin(x*k)','x','k');
tic,y = finline(x,2);toc
Elapsed time is 0.002546 seconds.
```

A neat thing about a function handle is you can define it on the fly. Minimize the function cos(x), over the interval [0,2*pi]?

```
xmin = fminbnd(@(x) cos(x),0,2*pi)
xmin =
          3.14159265358979
```

There are many, many other uses for function handles in MATLAB. I've only scratched the surface here.

Answer (score 15):

Disclaimer: code not tested...

The function handle operator allows you to create a reference to a function and pass it around just like any other variable:

```
% function to add two numbers
function total = add(first, second) 
    total = first + second;
end

% this variable now points to the add function
operation = @add;
```

Once you've got a function handle, you can invoke it just like a regular function:

```
operation(10, 20); % returns 30
```

One nice thing about function handles is that you can pass them around just like any other data, so you can write functions that act on other functions. This often allows you to easily separate out business logic:

```
% prints hello
function sayHello 
    disp('hello world!');
end

% does something five times
function doFiveTimes(thingToDo) 
    for idx = 1 : 5 
        thingToDo();
    end
end

% now I can say hello five times easily:
doFiveTimes(@sayHello);

% if there's something else I want to do five times, I don't have to write
% the five times logic again, only the operation itself:
function sayCheese 
    disp('Cheese');
end
doFiveTimes(@sayCheese);

% I don't even need to explicitly declare a function - this is an 
% anonymous function:
doFiveTimes(@() disp('do something else'));
```

The [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/function_handle.html) has a fuller description of the Matlab syntax, and describes some other uses for function handles like graphics callbacks.