# Defining function in matlab which uses a function as a parameter

Tags: matlab

I want to define a function like this:

```
function f = f1(fun,a,b,c)
f = c*fun(a+b);
```

Here `fun` is some function that I will pass when I use the function `f`.
How can I do this in Matlab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried it? The best way to learn a tool like matlab is to try things!

In fact, you don't even need to create an m-file function. I'll do it using a function handle here.

```
fun = @(x) sin(x);
f1 = @(f,a,b,c) c*f(a+b);
f1(fun,2,3,4)

ans =
      -3.8357
```

I could have defined f1 as an m-file function too, but that would have required I save a file. Why bother?

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is the [function handle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/function_handle.html).

You can obtain the function handle of a function (in the following case, `sqrt`) by placing the "at" symbol ('@') in front of the function name:

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 3;
fun = @sqrt;        % obtain the function handle of sqrt()
f = f1(fun, a,b,c); % pass the function handle of sqrt() into your function f1().
```

When you use `fun`, it will be as if you are using the `sqrt` function.

For more details, you may also refer to another Stackoverflow question: [function handle in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796935/function-handle-in-matlab)