# Matlab: how to receive a function (like exp) as an argument in my routine?

Tags: matlab, math

I'm programming the montecarlo method for solving integrals. My vector with abscissas is defined inside the routine. As such, i'd like to be able to receive a function to be integrated as an argument in my routine, instead of having to manually change it every time in my code.

How can I do this? Where should I read about this?

Thanks.

Comment: With the information you provide, [@surgical_tubing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32364440/2586922)'s answer is about the best that can be given. If you need more specific help, post a minimal example of your code and explain what you want to do

Comment: Here are some decent examples using function handles. http://stackoverflow.com/a/797450/931379

Comment: Thanks. surgical_tubing's answer has done it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function handles sound like what you want:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html