# Difference between a function handle and function

Tags: matlab, function

What is the difference between a function handle and a function itself in MATLAB? Is it like the difference between a function pointer and function in C/C++?

Comment: Related/Possible duplicate: [What is a function handle and how is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/796935/52738)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea about C/C++ but in MATLAB a function is a non-anonymous program which (possibly) takes input and (possibly) gives output, and is defined using the `function` keyword, e.g.

```
function a = MySum(b)
    a = sum(b);
end
```

whereas a function handle is a sort of short-cut to a function which is *anonymous*, i.e. can't be called from outside that script. It is created using the `@` syntax:

```
f=@(b)sum(b);
```

The function is saved as a .m file, with the function name as file name, so, using the above example, `MySum.m`. Having saved this on your path, and defined the anonymous function as per the above this is how you call them:

```
b = [1 2];
f=@(b)sum(b);
aFunction = MySum(b); % = 3
aAnon = f(b); % =3
```

If we now have a new script on the same path, we can't use the anonymous function if we don't define it, try:

```
b = [1 2];
aFunction = MySum(b); % = 3
aAnon = f(b); % gives error that f is undefined
```

If you create a script outside your path, also the function itself will fail:

```
b = [1 2];
aFunction = MySum(b); % gives error that MySum is undefined
aAnon = f(b); % gives error that f is undefined
```

Function handles are used for several reasons, of which the two most prominent in my opinion: inside "disguised loop functions" such as `arrayfun` or `bsxfun` which require a syntax like `arrayfun(@function,array)`, or when using e.g. a certain combination of functions very often in a script, e.g. `nnz(rand(size(N)>M)`, to shorten the sequence:  `f = @(M,N)nnz(rand(size(N)>M)` and now one can call `f(N,M)` instead of `nnz(rand(size(N)>M)`.

Following [Wolfie's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49112539/difference-between-a-function-handle-and-function/49112588?noredirect=1#comment85231170_49112588) there is indeed a dual nature of a function handle: it can act as a pointer, i.e. how `f` in the above example is a pointer to the function `sum`, but can also be a function in it's own right, like the combination of functions `nnz(rand(size(N)>M)` or things like a polynomial: `f=@(b) b.^2 + 5*b + 1`.

---

*Note on the "possibly" takes in-/output:*

You could define a function as

```
function MySine()
    x = 1:10;
    y = sin(x);
    plot(x,y)
end
```

which is a perfectly valid function which takes no in- or output arguments.

Comment: Reader's note: a function handle can *act* like a pointer, in that your example `f=@(b)sum(b)` is a pointer to the function `sum`. Might be worth mentioning though that anonymous functions can be functions in their own right, like `f=@(b) b.^2 + 5*b + 1`

Comment: How about create function handle based on the existing ones? Like, what is the difference between  `f=@sum` and `sum`?

Comment: @Rickyim readability. It's perfectly possible (as I've shown with multiple functions in my example already), just difficult to read. It's also necessary in things like `arrayfun(@sum,array)`, also, as previously mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! Is the latter reason that it is not possible to pass the function 
 name itself to a function requiring function handle?

Comment: @Rickyim yes. You don't want to call the function itself within a call to `arrayfun`, but rather tell `arrayfun` that under the hood it needs to use that specific function. So in a sense that's a C/C++ like pointer I guess. `arrayfun(@sum,sum(array))` would work as well, then you use both the *function* sum, as well as the *handle* to it (basically you create a new array using `sum(array)` and let `arrayfun` operate on that using `sum`.) I suggest you just play around a bit with function handles and anonymous functions to get a feel for them.