# Multiple callbacks in a MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, function, callback, matlab-gui

I am trying to convert a character vector callback to a function handle. However, I am calling multiple callbacks which I assume I could create a cell array with anonymous functions?

Here is the code:

```
guiel.hPB(2)=uicontrol(guiel.cPanel(2),'Style','PushButton','Units','pixels',...
        'TooltipString',guiel.plotTt,...
        'Position',[cnst.bhspace 3*cnst.bvspace+2*cnst.bheight cnst.bwidth cnst.bheight],...
        'String','Run Simulation','fontsize',10,'FontWeight','Demi',...
        'CallBack','eval(codeblk.CLOSE_MDL_FCN); set(guiel.cPanel(4),''Visible'',''off'');set(guiel.APPWINDOW,''Resize'',''off''); primePlot;',...
        'Enable','off');
```

What I am trying to do is to write `codeblk.CLOSE_MDL_FCN` into a function handle and the rest to be anonymous function handles? However, I am not sure how I can do that.

```
codeblk.CLOSE_MDL_FCN = ['if  ~isempty(find_system(''Name'',vars.simfilename))'...
                     'vars.simtime = str2num(get_param(vars.simfilename,''StopTime''));'...
                     'set(guiel.hSimtime,''String'',num2str(vars.simtime));'...
                     'save_system(vars.simfilename);'...
                     'close_system(vars.simfilename);'...
                     'end'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea when [creating a callback](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/write-callbacks-using-the-programmatic-workflow.html#f16-1001315) using a [function handle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html) is that it is a *single* function to handle everything for when that GUI object is interacted with. Using a [cell array callback](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/write-callbacks-using-the-programmatic-workflow.html#brqow8p) is for when you need to pass additional data to the function, not for calling multiple functions. Here's how I would suggest you design your button callback:

```
guiel.hPB(2) = uicontrol(..., 'CallBack', @callback_hPB2, ...);
```

And you would then define two [nested functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/272511/52738):

```
function callback_hPB2(~, ~)
  close_fcn();
  set(guiel.cPanel(4), 'Visible', 'off');
  set(guiel.APPWINDOW, 'Resize', 'off');
  primePlot();
end

function close_fcn
  if ~isempty(find_system('Name', vars.simfilename))
    vars.simtime = str2num(get_param(vars.simfilename, 'StopTime'));
    set(guiel.hSimtime, 'String', num2str(vars.simtime));
    save_system(vars.simfilename);
    close_system(vars.simfilename);
  end
end
```