# How to access variables from base workspace within function?

Tags: matlab, matlab-gui

I am a nested function inside a function and I am calling variables from base workspace. Note that `guiel` is in base workspace.

```
function callback(~,~)
    vars.dropheight = str2num(get(edit(2),'String'));
    vars.armradius = str2num(get(edit(1),'String'));
    kiddies = get(guiel.hAX(3),'Children'); 
    delete(kiddies);
    clear kiddies;
    set(guiel.tfPanel,'Visible','off','Position',cnst.tfPanelpos);
    set(guiel.hAX(1),'Position',cnst.axpos1);
    if ishandle(guiel.hAX(2)) 
    set(guiel.hAX(2),'Position',cnst.axpos2); 
    end 
    eval(get(guiel.hPB(4),'Callback'));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way, in my opinion, is to store `guiel` into [guidata](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html?searchHighlight=guidata&s_tid=doc_srchtitle).

```
guidata(hFig, guiel); % hFig can be gcf for top figure
```

and access it in `callback` by

```
guiel = guidata(hFig);
```

One of the alternatives is to pass the variable as input to `callback` by defining it as

```
{@callback, guiel}
```

The callback function definition will be

```
function callback(~, ~, guiel)
```

If you really hate these methods, a simple way is to define it as global in `base` and your `callback`. But this is something one tries to avoid for both performance and code maintainability consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Best practices for GUI design are that you encapsulate your GUI and its operations in such a way that it *never* has to depend on the [base workspace](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html) to function correctly. The reason? The user and other programs can modify anything in the base workspace, and can thus easily break your GUI.

I give an example of a basic GUI setup using [nested functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/425347/52738). Here's a general skeleton for designing a GUI:

```
function create_GUI()

  % Initialize data:
  data1 = ...;
  data2 = ...;

  % Create GUI:
  hFigure = figure;
  hObject1 = uicontrol(..., 'Callback', @callback1);
  hObject2 = uicontrol(..., 'Callback', @callback2);
  ....

  function callback1(~, ~)
    % Access any data or handles from above
    ...
  end

  function callback1(~, ~)
    % Access any data or handles from above
    ...
  end

end
```

The idea is that the main function creates all the GUI components, initializing all the needed data and object handles. The callbacks nested within the main function will have access to the data and handles as needed. I suggest designing your GUI like this, or using one of the other options listed [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/ways-to-build-matlab-guis.html). This should alleviate some of your data access issues and make your GUI more robust.